# GetStartupInfo() differs according to the explorer the app is launching from

Tags: c++, windows-7

I have a C++ app that launches another one with CreateProcess(). I fill the STARTUPINFO data with GetStartupInfo() before. Here is the code:

```
STARTUPINFOA si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

GetStartupInfoA( &si );

cout << si.dwFlags << endl;
cout << si.hStdError << endl;
cout << si.hStdInput << endl;
cout << si.hStdOutput << endl;
```

I use Win7/x64, SP1, VS2005, ICC 9.1 (Intel)

When I start the app from **CubicExplorer** it returns:

dwFlags = 1

hStdError = 0xffffffffffffffff

hStdInput = 0xffffffffffffffff

hStdOutput = 0xffffffffffffffff

(...and the second app I'm starting with CreateProcess using this STARTUPINFO works.)

When I start the app from the standard **Windows Explorer** it returns:

dwFlags = 1025 (0x401)

hStdError = 0x0000000000000000

hStdInput = 0x0000000000000000

hStdOutput = 0x0000000000010001

(... and CreateProcess fails with the error ACCESS_DENIED.)

My question: since the only difference is that the application is launched from a different folder explorer (**Windows Explorer** vs **Cubic Explorer**) what can produce these different info?

Comment: Very hard to answer without seeing the code of your C++ launcher app.

Comment: I understand... But the executable is [here](http://www.cubicreality.com/ce/). I already asked the same question on there forum. I'm a little mystified.

Comment: Well, if you won't show me how you call `CreateProcess`, I can't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `STARTUPINFO` record you receive comes from the `CreateProcess` call that started your program. Two different and completely independent programs called `CreateProcess`, and they evidently chose to populate the `STARTUPINFO` record differently. Nothing remarkable about that.

Incidentally, unless `dwFlags` includes `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`, it's meaningless to read the `hStdX` fields.

I recommend *not* simply forwarding your own startup parameters to the next program. Instead, explicitly populate exactly the startup fields you need for the next program. That wy, you know what you're getting.

Comment: In my winbase.h, STARTF_flags end at 0x200. On MS site ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx)) I didn't see any STARTF_ flag with a value of 0x400. Why do I get 0x401 which is probably 0x400|STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW ?

Comment: According to [an article about undocumented `CreateProcess`](http://catch22.net/tuts/undoc01), the flag value 0x400 is used to indicate which monitor the program should use. In that case, the `hStdOutput` field holds a monitor handle instead of a file handle. If the handle isn't set to be inherited by child processes, that would explain why you get an access-denied error when you blindly forward it to the next process.

Comment: I filled the STARTUPINFO with **exactly** the same values I got when the app worked. It still fails. Bug is elsewhere. Thanks for your link to the undocumented CreateProcess... ;-)

Comment: My CreateProcess is like this: CreateProcess(NULL,cmdline,NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE|CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi). I guess that (according to the fact that STARTUPINFO doesn't change anything) the problem comes from one of the arguments of CreateProcess. Maybe to much **NULL** ?

Comment: My advice is to stop filling the startup info with values you "got" and start filling them with the values *you* determine you need. I have no idea whether you've specified too many null parameters because I don't know what the correct parameters are for your program. Only you can know that from reading the documentation and considering *your* needs. I'd start by setting *only* the `cb` field, and setting everything else to zero. See whether *that* works.

Comment: Well... I filled the STARTUPINFO with the values I want and I still face the same behavior.

Comment: Then I suggest you post a new question. This question has been answered. In your new question, include the details necessary to reproduce the problem. Show the preparation and call of CreateProcess, and say what its return value is and what GetLastError reports.

Comment: No, the question is not answered at all. I still don't know why the two explorers produce such different behavior. And I still don't know how to overcome it. But I can't reproduce the problem with another (say a test) application yet. So, thanks for all your help!

Comment: I told you why they produce different behavior. Microsoft wrote Windows Explorer and made it call CreateProcess one way, whereas Cubic Reality wrote Cubic Explorer and made it call CreateProcess another way. That's all. There's nothing to overcome because there's no problem with the way your program is being started. There *is* a problem with how you're starting the next problem, but that has nothing to do with either explorer program.